# Cannot get hover state working with Magnific Popup

Tags: css, magnific-popup

I have an image and background hover state working on my thumbnails, however I can only seem to either get the hover state or Magnific popup working, never both.

My overlay is triggered by the div class "overlay"

Here is the HTML for the image that pops up (without functioning overlay):

```
<ul id="Grid">
    <li class="mix category_1 mix_all">
        <div class="overlay"> <a href="http://i.imgur.com/i5SwjyO.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/J4PaouI.jpg" alt="#"></a>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the HTML for the image that has a working overlay (but the image popup does not work):

```
<ul id="Grid">
    <li class="mix category_2 mix_all"> <a href="http://i.imgur.com/i5SwjyO.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/J4PaouI.jpg" alt="#"></a>

        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </li>
    <ul>
```

Here is the relevant hoverstate CSS:

```
.mix_all:hover .overlay {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DZcK9ge.png) no-repeat center !important;
    background-color: #de6573 !important;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

And here is the jsfiddle which has both examples: http://jsfiddle.net/yashar/wz4BT/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to fix the HTML structure a bit, and also added two separate JS events: the magnificPopup event applied to the .mix selector, and a click event applied to the overlays to allow them to click through to the anchor tag and trigger the popup event.

Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/GQZVR/

Html:

```
<ul id="Grid">
    <li class="mix category_1 mix_all">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <a href="http://i.imgur.com/i5SwjyO.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/J4PaouI.jpg" alt="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="mix category_2 mix_all"> 
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <a href="http://i.imgur.com/i5SwjyO.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/J4PaouI.jpg" alt="#"></a>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS (added cursor: pointer):

```
.mix_all .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.overlay')
    .click(function(){
        $(this).next('a').trigger('click');
    });
$('.mix')
    .magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
        gallery: {
            enabled: false //disabling the gallery for now
        },
        type: 'image' //type of lightbox
    });
```